# Login by cookies in python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

My intention is load gmail with out login google account.Is any possible to add cookies to the driver and login browser.For example if am wants to access same gmail multiple times means i am need to login google account each time.Is any possible to without login like browser session or cookies.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  And automating gmail is notoriously fragile; I'd suggest using the gmail API.

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me to login with cookies in selenium with python

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://mail.google.com")
with open("cookies.json") as d:
    cookies=json.load(d)
for cookie in cookies:
    cookie_copy=cookie
    cookie_copy["secure"]=False
    cookie_copy["domain"]="google.com"
    print(cookie_copy)
    try:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie_copy)
    except Exception as e:
        print("eerr i",e)
driver.get("https://mail.google.com")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new Webdriver() / RemoteDriver();
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies(); //It will get all cookies
```

The Above code will get all the cookies from the logged-in browser. You can set these cookies again to newly created browser. Cookies will be set only when the cookie domain is matched.

```
for(Cookie eachCookie : cookies) 
{
   driver.manage().addCookie(eachCookie);
}
```